# Почему указатель на символ символьного массива изменяется?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Скажите почему происходит такая аномалия, а точнее указатель на 2-ой символ символьного массива изменяется почему-то?

> ```
> 00000000000A2390 00000000000A22D0
> 00000000000A2390 00000000000A2391
> ```

```
void InitStr(string1 *s, unsigned n){
    *(s) = malloc((n+4) * sizeof(char));
    *(s[0]) = (char)CHAR_MIN+(char)n;
    *(s[1]) = (char)CHAR_MIN;
    printf("%p %p\n",s[0],s[1]);
}

unsigned Length(string1 s){
    printf("%p %p\n",&s[0],&s[1]);
}
```

Comment: Что такое у вас `string1`?

Comment: @Harry typedef char *string1

Comment: Написана какая-то белиберда. И где вызывающий код? Без вызывающего кода невозможно понять, что тут пытались сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что оно у вас вообще работает... Это вам как домашнее задание - разобраться, где **еще** у вас нелады.

А пока - что такое `s[0]` и `s[1]` в первой функции? Если `s` - указатель на указатель на `char`, т.е. образно - *указатель на строку*. Получается `s[0]` - указатель на строку, для которой выделена память, `s[1]` - указатель на следующую строку - если бы их у вас был массив.

А во второй - это просто адрес первого и второго символа строки.

Вот если бы вы в первой функции вызвали

```
printf("%p %p\n",&(*s)[0],&(*s)[1]);
```

то выводы в первой и второй функции у вас бы совпали.